# angular: change select options

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form with multiple selects.

- Select 1: Campus
- Select 2: Building
- Select 3: Floor
- Select 4: Room

Upon selecting an option from "Campus", I want the list of Buildings to change (updated from the database). And the same thing for the downstream selects.

Here's what I have so far... I can populate each select, but I don't know how to dynamically update them in situ.

#### form.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="campusForm">
    <select id="campus" formControlName="campus" [ngModel]="null" (ngModelChange)="selectCampus($event)>
        <option [ngValue]="null" selected="selected">All Campuses</option>
        <option [ngValue]="campus" *ngFor="let campus of campuses"> {{campus.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <select id="building" formControlName="building" [ngModel]="null" (ngModelChange)="selectBuilding($event)>
        <option [ngValue]="null" selected="selected">All Buildings</option>
        <option [ngValue]="building" *ngFor="let building of buildings"> {{campus.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <!-- etc... -->
</form>
```

#### form.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadCampuses();
  this.loadBuildings();
  //...
}

loadCampuses() {
  this.campusService.getCampuses().subscribe((res: Campus[]) => {
    this.campuses = res;
  });
}

selectCampuses(campus: Campus) {
  console.log (campus ? campus.name : "all campuses")
  this.loadBuildings(campus);
}

loadBuildings(campus: Campus) {
  this.buildingService.getBuildings(campus).subscribe((res: Building[]) => {
    this.buildings = res;
  });

  this.updateBuildingsSelect()
}

updateBuildingsSelect() {
  // This is where I'm stuck
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you shouldn't need to do anything; the dropdown should update itself based on `this.buildings = res;` Is this not what you're seeing? In any case, anything you do will need to be initiated from that subscription function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't to an `[ngModel]="null"`. Like that, you're just making its value null no matter what. Fill it with some sensible value instead. For example:

**form.component.ts**

```
selectedCampus: Campus = null;
selectedBuilding: Building = null;

selectCampus(campus: Campus) {
    this.selectedCampus = campus;
}

selectBuilding(building: Building) {
    this.selectedBuilding = building;
}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedCampus">...</select>
<select [ngModel]="selectedBuilding">...</select>
```